# Django pagination returning %20 whitespace in URL

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I cannot figure out why Django pagination sometimes adds whitespace (`%20`) to the URL:

```
https://example.com/accounts/?page=2%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&q=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&ordering=-date_joined
```

It happens if I click the `Next` or a specific page button so I assume it has to do with the way the pagination is written. More spoecifically I think it has to do with `request.GET.items`. Do context managers use `request.GET.items`?

**pagination**:

```
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
<a class="btn btn-default btn-inactive mb-4 m-1"
   href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}
   {% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">Next</a>
<a class="btn btn-default btn-inactive mb-4 m-1"
   href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}
   {% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">Last</a>
{% endif %}
```

**view**:

```
class AccountStatusListView(AccountSearchMixin, ListView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employees/account_list.html'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_ordering(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering', '-is_active')
        return ordering

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(AccountStatusListView, self).get_queryset()

        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(
            supervisor__exact=self.request.user)) | queryset.filter(Q(
            supervisor__isnull=False)) | queryset.filter(Q(
            is_active__exact=False))

        ordering = self.get_ordering()
        if ordering and isinstance(ordering, str):
            ordering = (ordering,)
            queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)

        return queryset
```

Anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: The `for` loops will render spaces.

Comment: How can I get around this? Is there a way to avoid that? It is weird that it only happens sometimes. Do I have to be explicit about what I want to be appended to the URL? Seems inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `QueryDict` to the template, for example:

```
class AccountStatusListView(AccountSearchMixin, ListView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employees/account_list.html'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_params = self.request.GET.copy()
        get_params.pop('page', None)
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs, get_params=get_params)

    def get_ordering(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.GET.get('ordering', '-is_active')

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(AccountStatusListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(
            supervisor__exact=self.request.user)) | queryset.filter(Q(
            supervisor__isnull=False)) | queryset.filter(Q(
            is_active__exact=False))
        ordering = self.get_ordering()
        if ordering and isinstance(ordering, str):
            ordering = (ordering,)
            queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
        return queryset
```

In the template, you can then [**`.urlencode()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode) the `get_params`:

```
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
<a class="btn btn-default btn-inactive mb-4 m-1"
   href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ get_params.urlencode }}">Next</a>
<a class="btn btn-default btn-inactive mb-4 m-1"
   href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}&{{ get_params.urlencode }}">Last</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this out and my data does not show up. Thoughts on why this could be?

Comment: @DavidAlford: you did pass `get_params` to the context? I forgot to return the `super().get_context_data()`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But when I `print(get_params)` before popping out `'page'` it returns an empty QeuryDict: `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: @DavidAlford: does `request.GET` contains something else *besides* the `page` parameter?

Comment: It *should* contain `ordering` and a search `query`. Maybe I don't understand what you are doing by popping out `'page'` in `context_data` method. Can you explain what you are doing in the `context_data` method?

Comment: @DavilAlford: can you see that in *querystring* of the URL?

Comment: No, but it is because this is the first page of the `AccountListView`. I would not see it until the second page, right?

Comment: To be clear: when I go to my `AccountStatusListView` the list of data does not show up. There is nothing but `/accounts/` in the URL (which is expected on page 1 or before a query)

Comment: @DavidAlford: well the point is, then it is not in the passed data, and thus not in `request.GET`. Furthermore I don't see a reason to include in in the next pages, since it will again default to the logic you implemented. If you pass it through a form, it will be retained in the next calls.

Comment: @DavidAlford: if you make a query to the listview, so the url is `?ordering=bla`, then it will retain it in the next pages, so the query details will "persist" through the pages.

Comment: I am officially confused. Why when I add this `context_data` override does my data disappear (or not show up)? When I `print(queryset)` in the `get_queryset` method it shows `<QuerySet [<Employee: David>, <Employee: Test2 Dealer2>, <Employee: Test2 Dealer2>]>` but this data is not displaying anymore after altering my `context_data`

Comment: @DavidAlford: no, it does not, if you call it with `*args` and `**kwargs` we simply add an extra element `get_params` to the context. This is necessary in the template to add any other GET parameters to the new request.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work but posted an updated version of it below which works... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with the above answer working so I changed the code around a little bit... The final result looked as such:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    get_copy = self.request.GET.copy()
    parameters = get_copy.pop('page', True) and get_copy.urlencode()
    context['params'] = parameters
    return context
```

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
<a class="btn btn-default mb-4 m-1"
   href="?page=1&{{ params }}">
    First</a>
<a class="btn btn-default mb-4 m-1"
   href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&{{ params }}">
    Previous</a>
{% endif %}
```